# Can 'thanks to' suggest a tone of sarcasm?

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

'Thanks' is a word for gratitude, while 'thanks to' can be used for bad reasons. I wonder whether 'thanks to' can be sarcastic when used for something bad.

Comment: Thanks to a lack of effort, a lot of unnecessary questions appear on this site.

Comment: Thanks to the dedication of many members, they are often answered.

Comment: Thanks to your damn brother's amateur wiring, we had no light or heat for a week. Thanks to my wallet, and a proper electrician, we got them back. I would say that most people just use it as a variant of 'due to' and don't really think of sarcasm.

Answer (score 2):

Almost any evaluative phrase can be used sarcastically. *Thanks to* is no exception.